# issues with a small JS library

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm trying to write a small JS validation library, for fun and to learn JS. the idea is to loop through elements in a form tag, and to check whether an input element is valid, based on other custom attributes.

i'm now stuck on how to use an element to call a function in the same "prototype"

this is based on a tutorial that i'm trying to develop, let me know if SE policy require mentioning the source of this code

code will be called from html doc using this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function processForm() {
        _('form1').validate();
    }
</script>
```

this is the lib code:

```
function _(id) {
if (id) {
    if (window === this) {
        return new _(id);
    }

    // We're in the correct object scop:
    // Init our element object and return the object
    this.e = document.getElementById(id);
    return this;
} else {
    return "NO ID PARAM WAS GIVEN";
}
}
_.prototype = {
validate    :function () {
                try {
                    var elem = this.e.elements;
                    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
                        //alert(elem[i].getAttribute("id"));
                        // STUCK HERE, how to call the bgcolor function of this prototype
                        so i can change the bgcolor for the current elem of the loop ?
                    }
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
            },  

bgcolor: function (color) {
            this.e.style.background = color;
            return this;
        },
};
```

Comment: The way it's set up currently would change the background colour of the form, and not a form element.

Comment: You can use `this` in the prototype function, if I'm correct. So, `this.getAFormElement().bgColor = "#WHATEVER";` should work. (Except for the nonexistent getAFormElement() function.)

Comment: when i call a property of the dom element, say "value" that exist (elem[i].value="#FFCC00"; //works), this works, but not when i call my custom function bgcolor...i gues the prototype function is not reached, but throws no error by the catch block...weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
    this.bgcolor(elem[i], "red");
}
```

and

```
bgcolor: function (el, color) {
    el.style.background = color;
    return this;
}
```

or maybe an optional element that defaults to `this`, keeping in sync with your existing code that operates on the form itself.

```
bgcolor: function (color, el) {
    el = el || this;
    el.style.background = color;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: thanks, would it be nicer to take the el param out? i assume the function should look into the current element and work on it, this code will be executed once...begin to end so elements should  not be mistaken

Comment: If you take `el` out, you are changing the `style.background` of the form (the form === `this` in your code). Is that what you want? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: you're right, sorry being repetitive..the goal is to make the bgcolor function work with any element passed to the _ function...to allow chaining, it may seem weird :) but this is the part i need to understand in JS...and for which i chose to work on this tutorial.

Comment: Ok. So the first block in the suggested answer uses this.bgcolor to call your bgcolor method, but in order to change the colour of an element, and not the form itself, we need to pass the element to the method.

Comment: this line from inside the "validate" function works:        this.e.children[i].style.background = "#FFCC00";
but this doesn't : this.e.children[i].bgcolor("#FFCC00");

Comment: `bgcolor` is a property of the `prototype` of `_`. It is not connected or related to an item in `elements` or an item in `children` in any way. Why would you think `this.e.children[i].bgcolor(...)` would work? Think this is the misunderstanding.

Comment: that's what i just realized, any "casting" in JS ? :)

Comment: You could attach methods to `HTMLElement.prototype`, but it's usually considered bad practice to 'mess about' with the prototypes of such objects. It's arguably simpler, more obvious, and less prone to unintended consequences to do it as demonstrated in the answer.